# Obtaining stored procedures information

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, stored-procedures

I want to know information regarding stored procedures, such as who created the stored procedure, who is the author, and more.

I meant server wise, not definition from a book.

Comment: http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/10716/determining-how-a-schema-change-occurred

Answer (score 1):

Use this query to view some of the stored procedure's metadata:

```
select *   
  from information_schema.routines   
 where routine_type = 'PROCEDURE'
```

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at system tables such as sys.objects, they have information like creation date etc, may not have everything you are after though.

Comment: at least you know anyway to find who creates that object?

Comment: Try Schema Chanages History report

Answer (score 0):

```
select *
from sys.procedures
```

I think you've got a problem if you need to know the author though.

You could set up auditing for the future, but right now you might need to do without the author info.